# How to remove <null>'s from NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nsnull

I'm trying to use the writeToFile method of an `NSArray` of NSDictionaries which doesn't allow nulls. I figured just loop through and find them and replace with empty `NSString`'s but I can't get it to work. This is what I'm trying.

EDIT: The NSArrays and NSDictionaries are created by NSJSONSerialization.

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *mainDict in mainArray)
{
    for(NSMutableDictionary *subDict in mainDict)
    {
        for(NSString *key in subDict)
        {                
            id value = [subDict objectForKey:key];

            if (value == [NSNull null])
            {
                [subDict setObject:@"" forKey:key];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this throws an exception. `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'`

But as you can see all NSDictionaries are mutable.

What's up?
Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: Moved new version to a separate answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How do you know that the dictionaries are mutable? It looks like they’re not. Typing them as `NSMutableDictionary` during the enumeration doesn’t make them mutable. You could walk over the dictionary and move the keys into a new, mutable one, filtering the nulls.

Also, if your dictionary comes from `NSJSONSerialization`, take a look at `NSJSONReadingOptions`, there’s an option to use mutable containers for the deserialized structure. That’s not always a good solution, but it’s worth checking out.

As for mutating a dictionary while enumerating it: you can’t change the keys, since that could easily throw off the enumeration code. But I don’t see why you couldn’t change the key values, which is all you’re after. This code works:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [@{@"foo" : @"bar"} mutableCopy];
for (NSString *key in dict) {
    dict[key] = @"baz";
}
```

Comment: Also, mutating a dictionary while enumerating is an error and throws an exception.

Comment: Yeah..... I would suggest creating a seperate NSDictionary and setting it to this dictionary he is enumerating after the enumeration

Comment: Ok thanks. It's hard to know the structure of the tree as it's created by NSJSONSerialization. I've created a new version with mutable copies. Am I on the right track here or missing the point?

Comment: Ok that doesn't work because of what H2CO3 pointed out. I don't quite understand why that's not allowed but what would be the correct way?

Comment: I’ve expanded the answer (too much text to fit in a comment), hope that helps.

Comment: Note that `NSJSONSerialization` has an option `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` to create arrays and dictionaries as mutable objects.

Comment: Ok great, NSJSONReadingMutableContainers makes the first version valid except the setting of values. I've not encountered this syntax before though '@{@"foo" : @"bar"}'???

Comment: That’s [collection literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html), a recent addition to the language.

Comment: OK thanks so the first line is equivalent to 'NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"foo", @"bar, nil] mutableCopy];'. Also I realised the problem with that new version is I should be enumerating 'dict' while mutating 'newDict'.

Answer (score 0):

Or rebuilding the whole tree works.

```
NSMutableArray *newMainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSArray *subArray in self.mainArray)
{
    NSMutableArray *newSubArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(NSDictionary *dict in subArray)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        for(NSString *key in dict)
        {              
            id value = [dict objectForKey:key];
            if (value == [NSNull null])
            {
                [newDict setObject:@"" forKey:key];
            } else {
                [newDict setObject:value forKey:key];
            }
        }
        [newSubArray addObject:newdict];
        [newDict release];
    }
    [newMainArray addObject:newSubArray];
    [newSubArray release];
}
[self.mainArray release];     <----  ????
self.mainArray = newMainArray;
```

Comment: There is one more problem with this code. If I release self.mainArray before pointing it to newMainArray it throws an exception. The property is defined as '@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *mainArray;'. Can I just reassign it without releasing first?